# Window Login credentials

Tags: java

I want windows login credentials or windows login username using java.

I have done this

```
com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem NTSystem = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem();
    System.out.println(NTSystem.getName());
```

Ex:- Jboss Server is in my system and when i run application is my system its showing my system username and if i run same application in jboss using another system  then it is showing same my system username not  another user name... how can i achieve this